# lots of 3d sound in handsfree

Tags: noise, sound, 3d

My earphone gives lots of 3d sounds and when i eject little bit it sounds good, actually i’m repairing i-e change of jack. Kindly help

Your reply will be highly obliged.

Comment: What are "3D sounds?"

Comment: Most likely OP means the effect that happens with malfunctioning ground connection of headphones. When ground disconnects from the headphones, left and right driver elements are in series between left and right outputs, creating quite a spatial experience.

Comment: so how i can fix this

Comment: If ground disconnects, the resulting “experience” is monophonic and this can hardly be described as “spatial” or 3D .

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2femOlc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Full connection. (b) Lost ground connection.*

If you lose the common ground connection to your headphones then only the difference between the left and right channels will be heard. This will typically eliminate most of the bass as that is usually on the centre of the stereo panorama and therefore has the same signal on both channels. When both channels are outputting the same signal then there is no difference in voltage between left and right so no current will flow (for those frequencies) and you won't hear them.

You need to find where the broken earth connection is.